# Plot multiple plots on same figure using loops in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am trying to plot multiple columns from the same dataframe using a loop. Table below shows my dataframe:

```
       Time  Amount  Amount i=2  Amount i=3  Amount i=4
0    20      10          20          30          40
1    10       5          10          15          20
2    15      25          50          75          75
```

The desired outcome is to have the values for Amount i=2, Amount i=3, and Amount i=4, on the same figure using a loop.

The code below plots each of the 'Amounts' on a seperate plot.

```
for i in range(range1,range2):
        df.plot(x ='Time', y=['Amount i={}'.format(i)])
```

Any help how to plot them on 1 figure greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df.plot(x='Time', y = ['Amount i={}'.format(i) for i in range(r1,r2)])`.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I was after! appreciate it!

Comment: Hello, @QuangHoang, I was wondering if you knew how to complete this, if I had multiple variables. For example, 'Amount i={},j={}'.format(i,j) for i in range(r1,r2) & j in range(r2,r4). The example here doesnt work. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for i in range(2,5):
    plt.plot(df["Time"], df[f"Amount i={i}"]

# and do not forget 

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! for your help!